# Covering matrices and image reconstruction using numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, matrix

I am not very good using matrices and fairly new using numpy, but I have an image sliced in patches with covering ends, and I would like to reconstruct it summing the covering parts like this:

[image: Covering matrices and summing]

I am currently using this to reconstruct my image:

```
new_im = Image.new('L', (576,576)) #creating a new image
y = (vqr // u)*stride #calculating the position of the patch to "glue"
x = i % u*stride
new_im.paste(img, (x, y, x + w, y + h)) #pasting the patch to the new image
```

The current results produce an image in which the covering parts are not summed up. I know that summing matrices is not that simple that's why I ask for a bit of help

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't actually see what operation is happening in the figure. Can you explain this? And can you make this a minimal example by pasting small example arrays and the expected output?

Comment: the operation I want to do is summing only specific columns of 2 matrices together:
x = np.matrix([[1,1,1,1],[1,2,2,1],[1,2,2,1],[1,1,1,1]])
y = np.matrix([[7,7,7,7],[7,3,3,7],[7,3,3,7],[7,7,7,7]])

I want to "fuse" the last two columns of the first matrix and the last two columns of the second matrix (stride = 2). as the final would be

f = np.matrix([[1,1,8,8,7,7],[1,2,9,4,3,7],[1,2,9,4,3,7],[1,1,8,8,7,7]])

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: OH, so you're padding x on the right with two columns of zeros, then padding y on the left with two columns of zeros, and then adding. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't intend to pad them with zeros, but 'combining' the two matrices with their 'joining columns' (the 2 last ones of x and the 2 first ones of y) summed up and have a final matrix with a shape: f.shape = (4,6)

Comment: Yeah, that's a sum of padded arrays. I'm sure there are other ways to express it, but no vectorised one is obvious to me

Answer (score 2):

Just pad the matrices with the appropriate columns of zeros, then add like normal.

```
import numpy as np
# define inputs and desired output  
x = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,2,2,1],[1,2,2,1],[1,1,1,1]])
y = np.array([[7,7,7,7],[7,3,3,7],[7,3,3,7],[7,7,7,7]])  
f = np.array([[1,1,8,8,7,7],[1,2,9,4,3,7],[1,2,9,4,3,7],[1,1,8,8,7,7]]) 

shape = (x.shape[0],x.shape[1]+2) # the shape of the desired output
xpad = np.zeros(shape) # pad the x array on the left with two columns of 0
ypad = np.zeros(shape) # and pad the y array on the right with two columns
xpad[:,:-2]=x # like this 
ypad[:,2:]=y
f_ = xpad+ypad # and then do the addition to get f_ the actual output
np.alltrue(f_==f) #True -- it works
```

A comment: you probably don't want `np.matrix`. I think they're going to depreciate it. For most purposes it does nothing `np.array` can't do more generally.

another way which is harder to read is

```
f_ = np.pad(x,((0,0),(0,2)),'constant')+np.pad(y,((0,0),(2,0)),'constant')
```

You can easily extend this to your case. Pad each array with zeros to the appropriate shape and then sum it